# inner join with cake php 3

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-3.0

Help Please , I'm trying to get data from multi tables : first table is contain ( more than 3 tables ) , the second table have data related to the first table .

I have used Inner Join at Php myadmin and it's working fine !
but when i have return that to cake php , it's doesn't work fine .

here's my code :

```
 $query= $this->SterilizationTaskOrders->find('all',array('contain'=>[ 'Users','SterilizationTasks', 'SterilizationTypes', 'SterilizationTaskTypes', 'SterilizationStatuses'],)) ->join([
            'supervision_data' => [
                'table' => 'supervision_data',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => 'supervision_data.sterilization_task_orders_id =SterilizationTaskOrders.id ',
            ] ])->toArray();
```

And here's the sql statement which i have used in phpmyadmin and has been worked fine !

> SELECT * FROM `sterilization_task_orders` INNER JOIN `supervision_data` ON sterilization_task_orders_id =sterilization_task_orders.id

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= $this->SterilizationTaskOrders->find()
    ->contain=>[ 'Users','SterilizationTasks', 'SterilizationTypes', 'SterilizationTaskTypes', 'SterilizationStatuses']
    ->join([

                'table' => 'supervision_data',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'alias' => 's',
                'conditions' => 's.id = supervision_data.sterilization_task_orders_id',
             ])
->toArray();
```

Please use this. Though I didn't test. But, hopefully, it will work.

Better you could write association in both table. Cake bake will generate it automatically. Then could date by contain.

thanks